# Error in SOAP UI to import WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to import a WSDL in Soap UI and I am getting the error below.

```
    Error loading [file:\C:\Users\P\Desktop\CurrencyConvertor.wsdl]: 

org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: does not close tag
```

It seems some tag is not closed . My WSDL seems to be properly formatted and I am not sure what could be the problem

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
            <s:element name="ConversionRate">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FromCurrency" type="tns:Currency"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ToCurrency" type="tns:Currency"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:simpleType name="Currency">
                <s:restriction base="s:string">
                    <s:enumeration value="AFA"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ALL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="DZD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ARS"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="AWG"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="AUD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BSD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BHD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BDT"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BBD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BZD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BMD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BTN"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BOB"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BWP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BRL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GBP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BND"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="BIF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XOF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XAF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KHR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CAD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CVE"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KYD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CLP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CNY"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="COP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KMF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CRC"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="HRK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CUP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CYP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CZK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="DKK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="DJF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="DOP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XCD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="EGP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SVC"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="EEK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ETB"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="EUR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="FKP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GMD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GHC"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GIP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XAU"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GTQ"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GNF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="GYD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="HTG"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="HNL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="HKD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="HUF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ISK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="INR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="IDR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="IQD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ILS"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="JMD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="JPY"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="JOD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KZT"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KES"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KRW"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KWD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LAK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LVL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LBP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LSL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LRD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LYD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LTL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MOP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MKD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MGF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MWK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MYR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MVR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MTL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MRO"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MUR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MXN"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MDL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MNT"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MAD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MZM"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="MMK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="NAD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="NPR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ANG"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="NZD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="NIO"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="NGN"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="KPW"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="NOK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="OMR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XPF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PKR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XPD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PAB"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PGK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PYG"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PEN"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PHP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XPT"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="PLN"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="QAR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ROL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="RUB"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="WST"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="STD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SAR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SCR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SLL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="XAG"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SGD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SKK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SIT"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SBD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SOS"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ZAR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="LKR"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SHP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SDD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SRG"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SZL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SEK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="CHF"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="SYP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TWD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TZS"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="THB"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TOP"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TTD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TND"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TRL"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="USD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="AED"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="UGX"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="UAH"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="UYU"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="VUV"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="VEB"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="VND"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="YER"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="YUM"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ZMK"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="ZWD"/>
                    <s:enumeration value="TRY"/>
                </s:restriction>
            </s:simpleType>
            <s:element name="ConversionRateResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ConversionRateResult" type="s:double"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="double" type="s:double"/>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="ConversionRateSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConversionRate"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ConversionRateSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConversionRateResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpGetIn">
        <wsdl:part name="FromCurrency" type="s:string"/>
        <wsdl:part name="ToCurrency" type="s:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpGetOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:double"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpPostIn">
        <wsdl:part name="FromCurrency" type="s:string"/>
        <wsdl:part name="ToCurrency" type="s:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpPostOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:double"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="CurrencyConvertorSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
                <br><b>Get conversion rate from one currency to another currency <b><br><p><b><font color='#000080' size='1' face='Verdana'><u>Differenct currency Code and Names around the world</u></font></b></p><blockquote><p><font face='Verdana' size='1'>AFA-Afghanistan Afghani<br>ALL-Albanian Lek<br>DZD-Algerian Dinar<br>ARS-Argentine Peso<br>AWG-Aruba Florin<br>AUD-Australian Dollar<br>BSD-Bahamian Dollar<br>BHD-Bahraini Dinar<br>BDT-Bangladesh Taka<br>BBD-Barbados Dollar<br>BZD-Belize Dollar<br>BMD-Bermuda Dollar<br>BTN-Bhutan Ngultrum<br>BOB-Bolivian Boliviano<br>BWP-Botswana Pula<br>BRL-Brazilian Real<br>GBP-British Pound<br>BND-Brunei Dollar<br>BIF-Burundi Franc<br>XOF-CFA Franc (BCEAO)<br>XAF-CFA Franc (BEAC)<br>KHR-Cambodia Riel<br>CAD-Canadian Dollar<br>CVE-Cape Verde Escudo<br>KYD-Cayman Islands Dollar<br>CLP-Chilean Peso<br>CNY-Chinese Yuan<br>COP-Colombian Peso<br>KMF-Comoros Franc<br>CRC-Costa Rica Colon<br>HRK-Croatian Kuna<br>CUP-Cuban Peso<br>CYP-Cyprus Pound<br>CZK-Czech Koruna<br>DKK-Danish Krone<br>DJF-Dijibouti Franc<br>DOP-Dominican Peso<br>XCD-East Caribbean Dollar<br>EGP-Egyptian Pound<br>SVC-El Salvador Colon<br>EEK-Estonian Kroon<br>ETB-Ethiopian Birr<br>EUR-Euro<br>FKP-Falkland Islands Pound<br>GMD-Gambian Dalasi<br>GHC-Ghanian Cedi<br>GIP-Gibraltar Pound<br>XAU-Gold Ounces<br>GTQ-Guatemala Quetzal<br>GNF-Guinea Franc<br>GYD-Guyana Dollar<br>HTG-Haiti Gourde<br>HNL-Honduras Lempira<br>HKD-Hong Kong Dollar<br>HUF-Hungarian Forint<br>ISK-Iceland Krona<br>INR-Indian Rupee<br>IDR-Indonesian Rupiah<br>IQD-Iraqi Dinar<br>ILS-Israeli Shekel<br>JMD-Jamaican Dollar<br>JPY-Japanese Yen<br>JOD-Jordanian Dinar<br>KZT-Kazakhstan Tenge<br>KES-Kenyan Shilling<br>KRW-Korean Won<br>KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar<br>LAK-Lao Kip<br>LVL-Latvian Lat<br>LBP-Lebanese Pound<br>LSL-Lesotho Loti<br>LRD-Liberian Dollar<br>LYD-Libyan Dinar<br>LTL-Lithuanian Lita<br>MOP-Macau Pataca<br>MKD-Macedonian Denar<br>MGF-Malagasy Franc<br>MWK-Malawi Kwacha<br>MYR-Malaysian Ringgit<br>MVR-Maldives Rufiyaa<br>MTL-Maltese Lira<br>MRO-Mauritania Ougulya<br>MUR-Mauritius Rupee<br>MXN-Mexican Peso<br>MDL-Moldovan Leu<br>MNT-Mongolian Tugrik<br>MAD-Moroccan Dirham<br>MZM-Mozambique Metical<br>MMK-Myanmar Kyat<br>NAD-Namibian Dollar<br>NPR-Nepalese Rupee<br>ANG-Neth Antilles Guilder<br>NZD-New Zealand Dollar<br>NIO-Nicaragua Cordoba<br>NGN-Nigerian Naira<br>KPW-North Korean Won<br>NOK-Norwegian Krone<br>OMR-Omani Rial<br>XPF-Pacific Franc<br>PKR-Pakistani Rupee<br>XPD-Palladium Ounces<br>PAB-Panama Balboa<br>PGK-Papua New Guinea Kina<br>PYG-Paraguayan Guarani<br>PEN-Peruvian Nuevo Sol<br>PHP-Philippine Peso<br>XPT-Platinum Ounces<br>PLN-Polish Zloty<br>QAR-Qatar Rial<br>ROL-Romanian Leu<br>RUB-Russian Rouble<br>WST-Samoa Tala<br>STD-Sao Tome Dobra<br>SAR-Saudi Arabian Riyal<br>SCR-Seychelles Rupee<br>SLL-Sierra Leone Leone<br>XAG-Silver Ounces<br>SGD-Singapore Dollar<br>SKK-Slovak Koruna<br>SIT-Slovenian Tolar<br>SBD-Solomon Islands Dollar<br>SOS-Somali Shilling<br>ZAR-South African Rand<br>LKR-Sri Lanka Rupee<br>SHP-St Helena Pound<br>SDD-Sudanese Dinar<br>SRG-Surinam Guilder<br>SZL-Swaziland Lilageni<br>SEK-Swedish Krona<br>TRY-Turkey Lira<br>CHF-Swiss Franc<br>SYP-Syrian Pound<br>TWD-Taiwan Dollar<br>TZS-Tanzanian Shilling<br>THB-Thai Baht<br>TOP-Tonga Pa'anga<br>TTD-Trinidad&amp;amp;Tobago Dollar<br>TND-Tunisian Dinar<br>TRL-Turkish Lira<br>USD-U.S. Dollar<br>AED-UAE Dirham<br>UGX-Ugandan Shilling<br>UAH-Ukraine Hryvnia<br>UYU-Uruguayan New Peso<br>VUV-Vanuatu Vatu<br>VEB-Venezuelan Bolivar<br>VND-Vietnam Dong<br>YER-Yemen Riyal<br>YUM-Yugoslav Dinar<br>ZMK-Zambian Kwacha<br>ZWD-Zimbabwe Dollar</font></p></blockquote>
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ConversionRateSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ConversionRateSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:portType name="CurrencyConvertorHttpGet">
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
                <br><b>Get conversion rate from one currency to another currency <b><br><p><b><font color='#000080' size='1' face='Verdana'><u>Differenct currency Code and Names around the world</u></font></b></p><blockquote><p><font face='Verdana' size='1'>AFA-Afghanistan Afghani<br>ALL-Albanian Lek<br>DZD-Algerian Dinar<br>ARS-Argentine Peso<br>AWG-Aruba Florin<br>AUD-Australian Dollar<br>BSD-Bahamian Dollar<br>BHD-Bahraini Dinar<br>BDT-Bangladesh Taka<br>BBD-Barbados Dollar<br>BZD-Belize Dollar<br>BMD-Bermuda Dollar<br>BTN-Bhutan Ngultrum<br>BOB-Bolivian Boliviano<br>BWP-Botswana Pula<br>BRL-Brazilian Real<br>GBP-British Pound<br>BND-Brunei Dollar<br>BIF-Burundi Franc<br>XOF-CFA Franc (BCEAO)<br>XAF-CFA Franc (BEAC)<br>KHR-Cambodia Riel<br>CAD-Canadian Dollar<br>CVE-Cape Verde Escudo<br>KYD-Cayman Islands Dollar<br>CLP-Chilean Peso<br>CNY-Chinese Yuan<br>COP-Colombian Peso<br>KMF-Comoros Franc<br>CRC-Costa Rica Colon<br>HRK-Croatian Kuna<br>CUP-Cuban Peso<br>CYP-Cyprus Pound<br>CZK-Czech Koruna<br>DKK-Danish Krone<br>DJF-Dijibouti Franc<br>DOP-Dominican Peso<br>XCD-East Caribbean Dollar<br>EGP-Egyptian Pound<br>SVC-El Salvador Colon<br>EEK-Estonian Kroon<br>ETB-Ethiopian Birr<br>EUR-Euro<br>FKP-Falkland Islands Pound<br>GMD-Gambian Dalasi<br>GHC-Ghanian Cedi<br>GIP-Gibraltar Pound<br>XAU-Gold Ounces<br>GTQ-Guatemala Quetzal<br>GNF-Guinea Franc<br>GYD-Guyana Dollar<br>HTG-Haiti Gourde<br>HNL-Honduras Lempira<br>HKD-Hong Kong Dollar<br>HUF-Hungarian Forint<br>ISK-Iceland Krona<br>INR-Indian Rupee<br>IDR-Indonesian Rupiah<br>IQD-Iraqi Dinar<br>ILS-Israeli Shekel<br>JMD-Jamaican Dollar<br>JPY-Japanese Yen<br>JOD-Jordanian Dinar<br>KZT-Kazakhstan Tenge<br>KES-Kenyan Shilling<br>KRW-Korean Won<br>KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar<br>LAK-Lao Kip<br>LVL-Latvian Lat<br>LBP-Lebanese Pound<br>LSL-Lesotho Loti<br>LRD-Liberian Dollar<br>LYD-Libyan Dinar<br>LTL-Lithuanian Lita<br>MOP-Macau Pataca<br>MKD-Macedonian Denar<br>MGF-Malagasy Franc<br>MWK-Malawi Kwacha<br>MYR-Malaysian Ringgit<br>MVR-Maldives Rufiyaa<br>MTL-Maltese Lira<br>MRO-Mauritania Ougulya<br>MUR-Mauritius Rupee<br>MXN-Mexican Peso<br>MDL-Moldovan Leu<br>MNT-Mongolian Tugrik<br>MAD-Moroccan Dirham<br>MZM-Mozambique Metical<br>MMK-Myanmar Kyat<br>NAD-Namibian Dollar<br>NPR-Nepalese Rupee<br>ANG-Neth Antilles Guilder<br>NZD-New Zealand Dollar<br>NIO-Nicaragua Cordoba<br>NGN-Nigerian Naira<br>KPW-North Korean Won<br>NOK-Norwegian Krone<br>OMR-Omani Rial<br>XPF-Pacific Franc<br>PKR-Pakistani Rupee<br>XPD-Palladium Ounces<br>PAB-Panama Balboa<br>PGK-Papua New Guinea Kina<br>PYG-Paraguayan Guarani<br>PEN-Peruvian Nuevo Sol<br>PHP-Philippine Peso<br>XPT-Platinum Ounces<br>PLN-Polish Zloty<br>QAR-Qatar Rial<br>ROL-Romanian Leu<br>RUB-Russian Rouble<br>WST-Samoa Tala<br>STD-Sao Tome Dobra<br>SAR-Saudi Arabian Riyal<br>SCR-Seychelles Rupee<br>SLL-Sierra Leone Leone<br>XAG-Silver Ounces<br>SGD-Singapore Dollar<br>SKK-Slovak Koruna<br>SIT-Slovenian Tolar<br>SBD-Solomon Islands Dollar<br>SOS-Somali Shilling<br>ZAR-South African Rand<br>LKR-Sri Lanka Rupee<br>SHP-St Helena Pound<br>SDD-Sudanese Dinar<br>SRG-Surinam Guilder<br>SZL-Swaziland Lilageni<br>SEK-Swedish Krona<br>TRY-Turkey Lira<br>CHF-Swiss Franc<br>SYP-Syrian Pound<br>TWD-Taiwan Dollar<br>TZS-Tanzanian Shilling<br>THB-Thai Baht<br>TOP-Tonga Pa'anga<br>TTD-Trinidad&amp;amp;Tobago Dollar<br>TND-Tunisian Dinar<br>TRL-Turkish Lira<br>USD-U.S. Dollar<br>AED-UAE Dirham<br>UGX-Ugandan Shilling<br>UAH-Ukraine Hryvnia<br>UYU-Uruguayan New Peso<br>VUV-Vanuatu Vatu<br>VEB-Venezuelan Bolivar<br>VND-Vietnam Dong<br>YER-Yemen Riyal<br>YUM-Yugoslav Dinar<br>ZMK-Zambian Kwacha<br>ZWD-Zimbabwe Dollar</font></p></blockquote>
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ConversionRateHttpGetIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ConversionRateHttpGetOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:portType name="CurrencyConvertorHttpPost">
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
                <br><b>Get conversion rate from one currency to another currency <b><br><p><b><font color='#000080' size='1' face='Verdana'><u>Differenct currency Code and Names around the world</u></font></b></p><blockquote><p><font face='Verdana' size='1'>AFA-Afghanistan Afghani<br>ALL-Albanian Lek<br>DZD-Algerian Dinar<br>ARS-Argentine Peso<br>AWG-Aruba Florin<br>AUD-Australian Dollar<br>BSD-Bahamian Dollar<br>BHD-Bahraini Dinar<br>BDT-Bangladesh Taka<br>BBD-Barbados Dollar<br>BZD-Belize Dollar<br>BMD-Bermuda Dollar<br>BTN-Bhutan Ngultrum<br>BOB-Bolivian Boliviano<br>BWP-Botswana Pula<br>BRL-Brazilian Real<br>GBP-British Pound<br>BND-Brunei Dollar<br>BIF-Burundi Franc<br>XOF-CFA Franc (BCEAO)<br>XAF-CFA Franc (BEAC)<br>KHR-Cambodia Riel<br>CAD-Canadian Dollar<br>CVE-Cape Verde Escudo<br>KYD-Cayman Islands Dollar<br>CLP-Chilean Peso<br>CNY-Chinese Yuan<br>COP-Colombian Peso<br>KMF-Comoros Franc<br>CRC-Costa Rica Colon<br>HRK-Croatian Kuna<br>CUP-Cuban Peso<br>CYP-Cyprus Pound<br>CZK-Czech Koruna<br>DKK-Danish Krone<br>DJF-Dijibouti Franc<br>DOP-Dominican Peso<br>XCD-East Caribbean Dollar<br>EGP-Egyptian Pound<br>SVC-El Salvador Colon<br>EEK-Estonian Kroon<br>ETB-Ethiopian Birr<br>EUR-Euro<br>FKP-Falkland Islands Pound<br>GMD-Gambian Dalasi<br>GHC-Ghanian Cedi<br>GIP-Gibraltar Pound<br>XAU-Gold Ounces<br>GTQ-Guatemala Quetzal<br>GNF-Guinea Franc<br>GYD-Guyana Dollar<br>HTG-Haiti Gourde<br>HNL-Honduras Lempira<br>HKD-Hong Kong Dollar<br>HUF-Hungarian Forint<br>ISK-Iceland Krona<br>INR-Indian Rupee<br>IDR-Indonesian Rupiah<br>IQD-Iraqi Dinar<br>ILS-Israeli Shekel<br>JMD-Jamaican Dollar<br>JPY-Japanese Yen<br>JOD-Jordanian Dinar<br>KZT-Kazakhstan Tenge<br>KES-Kenyan Shilling<br>KRW-Korean Won<br>KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar<br>LAK-Lao Kip<br>LVL-Latvian Lat<br>LBP-Lebanese Pound<br>LSL-Lesotho Loti<br>LRD-Liberian Dollar<br>LYD-Libyan Dinar<br>LTL-Lithuanian Lita<br>MOP-Macau Pataca<br>MKD-Macedonian Denar<br>MGF-Malagasy Franc<br>MWK-Malawi Kwacha<br>MYR-Malaysian Ringgit<br>MVR-Maldives Rufiyaa<br>MTL-Maltese Lira<br>MRO-Mauritania Ougulya<br>MUR-Mauritius Rupee<br>MXN-Mexican Peso<br>MDL-Moldovan Leu<br>MNT-Mongolian Tugrik<br>MAD-Moroccan Dirham<br>MZM-Mozambique Metical<br>MMK-Myanmar Kyat<br>NAD-Namibian Dollar<br>NPR-Nepalese Rupee<br>ANG-Neth Antilles Guilder<br>NZD-New Zealand Dollar<br>NIO-Nicaragua Cordoba<br>NGN-Nigerian Naira<br>KPW-North Korean Won<br>NOK-Norwegian Krone<br>OMR-Omani Rial<br>XPF-Pacific Franc<br>PKR-Pakistani Rupee<br>XPD-Palladium Ounces<br>PAB-Panama Balboa<br>PGK-Papua New Guinea Kina<br>PYG-Paraguayan Guarani<br>PEN-Peruvian Nuevo Sol<br>PHP-Philippine Peso<br>XPT-Platinum Ounces<br>PLN-Polish Zloty<br>QAR-Qatar Rial<br>ROL-Romanian Leu<br>RUB-Russian Rouble<br>WST-Samoa Tala<br>STD-Sao Tome Dobra<br>SAR-Saudi Arabian Riyal<br>SCR-Seychelles Rupee<br>SLL-Sierra Leone Leone<br>XAG-Silver Ounces<br>SGD-Singapore Dollar<br>SKK-Slovak Koruna<br>SIT-Slovenian Tolar<br>SBD-Solomon Islands Dollar<br>SOS-Somali Shilling<br>ZAR-South African Rand<br>LKR-Sri Lanka Rupee<br>SHP-St Helena Pound<br>SDD-Sudanese Dinar<br>SRG-Surinam Guilder<br>SZL-Swaziland Lilageni<br>SEK-Swedish Krona<br>TRY-Turkey Lira<br>CHF-Swiss Franc<br>SYP-Syrian Pound<br>TWD-Taiwan Dollar<br>TZS-Tanzanian Shilling<br>THB-Thai Baht<br>TOP-Tonga Pa'anga<br>TTD-Trinidad&amp;amp;Tobago Dollar<br>TND-Tunisian Dinar<br>TRL-Turkish Lira<br>USD-U.S. Dollar<br>AED-UAE Dirham<br>UGX-Ugandan Shilling<br>UAH-Ukraine Hryvnia<br>UYU-Uruguayan New Peso<br>VUV-Vanuatu Vatu<br>VEB-Venezuelan Bolivar<br>VND-Vietnam Dong<br>YER-Yemen Riyal<br>YUM-Yugoslav Dinar<br>ZMK-Zambian Kwacha<br>ZWD-Zimbabwe Dollar</font></p></blockquote>
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ConversionRateHttpPostIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ConversionRateHttpPostOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorSoap" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorSoap12" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorHttpGet" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpGet">
        <http:binding verb="GET"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <http:operation location="/ConversionRate"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <http:urlEncoded/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorHttpPost" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpPost">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
            <http:operation location="/ConversionRate"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="CurrencyConvertor">
        <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorSoap" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorSoap12" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap12">
            <soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorHttpGet" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpGet">
            <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorHttpPost" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpPost">
            <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can any one Help?

Comment: The error message clearly says some tag is not closed.

Comment: Here's a crazy idea: Have you tried by process of elimination figuring out what the problem tag is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the wsdl for you:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
        <s:element name="ConversionRate">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FromCurrency" type="tns:Currency"/>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ToCurrency" type="tns:Currency"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:simpleType name="Currency">
            <s:restriction base="s:string">
                <s:enumeration value="AFA"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ALL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="DZD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ARS"/>
                <s:enumeration value="AWG"/>
                <s:enumeration value="AUD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BSD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BHD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BDT"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BBD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BZD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BMD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BTN"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BOB"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BWP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BRL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GBP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BND"/>
                <s:enumeration value="BIF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XOF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XAF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KHR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CAD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CVE"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KYD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CLP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CNY"/>
                <s:enumeration value="COP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KMF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CRC"/>
                <s:enumeration value="HRK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CUP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CYP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CZK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="DKK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="DJF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="DOP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XCD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="EGP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SVC"/>
                <s:enumeration value="EEK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ETB"/>
                <s:enumeration value="EUR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="FKP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GMD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GHC"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GIP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XAU"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GTQ"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GNF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="GYD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="HTG"/>
                <s:enumeration value="HNL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="HKD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="HUF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ISK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="INR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="IDR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="IQD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ILS"/>
                <s:enumeration value="JMD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="JPY"/>
                <s:enumeration value="JOD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KZT"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KES"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KRW"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KWD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LAK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LVL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LBP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LSL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LRD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LYD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LTL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MOP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MKD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MGF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MWK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MYR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MVR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MTL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MRO"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MUR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MXN"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MDL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MNT"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MAD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MZM"/>
                <s:enumeration value="MMK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="NAD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="NPR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ANG"/>
                <s:enumeration value="NZD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="NIO"/>
                <s:enumeration value="NGN"/>
                <s:enumeration value="KPW"/>
                <s:enumeration value="NOK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="OMR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XPF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PKR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XPD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PAB"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PGK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PYG"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PEN"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PHP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XPT"/>
                <s:enumeration value="PLN"/>
                <s:enumeration value="QAR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ROL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="RUB"/>
                <s:enumeration value="WST"/>
                <s:enumeration value="STD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SAR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SCR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SLL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="XAG"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SGD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SKK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SIT"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SBD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SOS"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ZAR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="LKR"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SHP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SDD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SRG"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SZL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SEK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="CHF"/>
                <s:enumeration value="SYP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TWD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TZS"/>
                <s:enumeration value="THB"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TOP"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TTD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TND"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TRL"/>
                <s:enumeration value="USD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="AED"/>
                <s:enumeration value="UGX"/>
                <s:enumeration value="UAH"/>
                <s:enumeration value="UYU"/>
                <s:enumeration value="VUV"/>
                <s:enumeration value="VEB"/>
                <s:enumeration value="VND"/>
                <s:enumeration value="YER"/>
                <s:enumeration value="YUM"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ZMK"/>
                <s:enumeration value="ZWD"/>
                <s:enumeration value="TRY"/>
            </s:restriction>
        </s:simpleType>
        <s:element name="ConversionRateResponse">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ConversionRateResult" type="s:double"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element name="double" type="s:double"/>
    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ConversionRateSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConversionRate"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ConversionRateSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConversionRateResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpGetIn">
    <wsdl:part name="FromCurrency" type="s:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="ToCurrency" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpGetOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:double"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="FromCurrency" type="s:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="ToCurrency" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ConversionRateHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:double"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="CurrencyConvertorSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            &lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Get conversion rate from one currency to another currency &lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font color=&#39;#000080&#39; size=&#39;1&#39; face=&#39;Verdana&#39;&gt;&lt;u&gt;Differenct currency Code and Names around the world&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;font face=&#39;Verdana&#39; size=&#39;1&#39;&gt;AFA-Afghanistan Afghani&lt;br&gt;ALL-Albanian Lek&lt;br&gt;DZD-Algerian Dinar&lt;br&gt;ARS-Argentine Peso&lt;br&gt;AWG-Aruba Florin&lt;br&gt;AUD-Australian Dollar&lt;br&gt;BSD-Bahamian Dollar&lt;br&gt;BHD-Bahraini Dinar&lt;br&gt;BDT-Bangladesh Taka&lt;br&gt;BBD-Barbados Dollar&lt;br&gt;BZD-Belize Dollar&lt;br&gt;BMD-Bermuda Dollar&lt;br&gt;BTN-Bhutan Ngultrum&lt;br&gt;BOB-Bolivian Boliviano&lt;br&gt;BWP-Botswana Pula&lt;br&gt;BRL-Brazilian Real&lt;br&gt;GBP-British Pound&lt;br&gt;BND-Brunei Dollar&lt;br&gt;BIF-Burundi Franc&lt;br&gt;XOF-CFA Franc (BCEAO)&lt;br&gt;XAF-CFA Franc (BEAC)&lt;br&gt;KHR-Cambodia Riel&lt;br&gt;CAD-Canadian Dollar&lt;br&gt;CVE-Cape Verde Escudo&lt;br&gt;KYD-Cayman Islands Dollar&lt;br&gt;CLP-Chilean Peso&lt;br&gt;CNY-Chinese Yuan&lt;br&gt;COP-Colombian Peso&lt;br&gt;KMF-Comoros Franc&lt;br&gt;CRC-Costa Rica Colon&lt;br&gt;HRK-Croatian Kuna&lt;br&gt;CUP-Cuban Peso&lt;br&gt;CYP-Cyprus Pound&lt;br&gt;CZK-Czech Koruna&lt;br&gt;DKK-Danish Krone&lt;br&gt;DJF-Dijibouti Franc&lt;br&gt;DOP-Dominican Peso&lt;br&gt;XCD-East Caribbean Dollar&lt;br&gt;EGP-Egyptian Pound&lt;br&gt;SVC-El Salvador Colon&lt;br&gt;EEK-Estonian Kroon&lt;br&gt;ETB-Ethiopian Birr&lt;br&gt;EUR-Euro&lt;br&gt;FKP-Falkland Islands Pound&lt;br&gt;GMD-Gambian Dalasi&lt;br&gt;GHC-Ghanian Cedi&lt;br&gt;GIP-Gibraltar Pound&lt;br&gt;XAU-Gold Ounces&lt;br&gt;GTQ-Guatemala Quetzal&lt;br&gt;GNF-Guinea Franc&lt;br&gt;GYD-Guyana Dollar&lt;br&gt;HTG-Haiti Gourde&lt;br&gt;HNL-Honduras Lempira&lt;br&gt;HKD-Hong Kong Dollar&lt;br&gt;HUF-Hungarian Forint&lt;br&gt;ISK-Iceland Krona&lt;br&gt;INR-Indian Rupee&lt;br&gt;IDR-Indonesian Rupiah&lt;br&gt;IQD-Iraqi Dinar&lt;br&gt;ILS-Israeli Shekel&lt;br&gt;JMD-Jamaican Dollar&lt;br&gt;JPY-Japanese Yen&lt;br&gt;JOD-Jordanian Dinar&lt;br&gt;KZT-Kazakhstan Tenge&lt;br&gt;KES-Kenyan Shilling&lt;br&gt;KRW-Korean Won&lt;br&gt;KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar&lt;br&gt;LAK-Lao Kip&lt;br&gt;LVL-Latvian Lat&lt;br&gt;LBP-Lebanese Pound&lt;br&gt;LSL-Lesotho Loti&lt;br&gt;LRD-Liberian Dollar&lt;br&gt;LYD-Libyan Dinar&lt;br&gt;LTL-Lithuanian Lita&lt;br&gt;MOP-Macau Pataca&lt;br&gt;MKD-Macedonian Denar&lt;br&gt;MGF-Malagasy Franc&lt;br&gt;MWK-Malawi Kwacha&lt;br&gt;MYR-Malaysian Ringgit&lt;br&gt;MVR-Maldives Rufiyaa&lt;br&gt;MTL-Maltese Lira&lt;br&gt;MRO-Mauritania Ougulya&lt;br&gt;MUR-Mauritius Rupee&lt;br&gt;MXN-Mexican Peso&lt;br&gt;MDL-Moldovan Leu&lt;br&gt;MNT-Mongolian Tugrik&lt;br&gt;MAD-Moroccan Dirham&lt;br&gt;MZM-Mozambique Metical&lt;br&gt;MMK-Myanmar Kyat&lt;br&gt;NAD-Namibian Dollar&lt;br&gt;NPR-Nepalese Rupee&lt;br&gt;ANG-Neth Antilles Guilder&lt;br&gt;NZD-New Zealand Dollar&lt;br&gt;NIO-Nicaragua Cordoba&lt;br&gt;NGN-Nigerian Naira&lt;br&gt;KPW-North Korean Won&lt;br&gt;NOK-Norwegian Krone&lt;br&gt;OMR-Omani Rial&lt;br&gt;XPF-Pacific Franc&lt;br&gt;PKR-Pakistani Rupee&lt;br&gt;XPD-Palladium Ounces&lt;br&gt;PAB-Panama Balboa&lt;br&gt;PGK-Papua New Guinea Kina&lt;br&gt;PYG-Paraguayan Guarani&lt;br&gt;PEN-Peruvian Nuevo Sol&lt;br&gt;PHP-Philippine Peso&lt;br&gt;XPT-Platinum Ounces&lt;br&gt;PLN-Polish Zloty&lt;br&gt;QAR-Qatar Rial&lt;br&gt;ROL-Romanian Leu&lt;br&gt;RUB-Russian Rouble&lt;br&gt;WST-Samoa Tala&lt;br&gt;STD-Sao Tome Dobra&lt;br&gt;SAR-Saudi Arabian Riyal&lt;br&gt;SCR-Seychelles Rupee&lt;br&gt;SLL-Sierra Leone Leone&lt;br&gt;XAG-Silver Ounces&lt;br&gt;SGD-Singapore Dollar&lt;br&gt;SKK-Slovak Koruna&lt;br&gt;SIT-Slovenian Tolar&lt;br&gt;SBD-Solomon Islands Dollar&lt;br&gt;SOS-Somali Shilling&lt;br&gt;ZAR-South African Rand&lt;br&gt;LKR-Sri Lanka Rupee&lt;br&gt;SHP-St Helena Pound&lt;br&gt;SDD-Sudanese Dinar&lt;br&gt;SRG-Surinam Guilder&lt;br&gt;SZL-Swaziland Lilageni&lt;br&gt;SEK-Swedish Krona&lt;br&gt;TRY-Turkey Lira&lt;br&gt;CHF-Swiss Franc&lt;br&gt;SYP-Syrian Pound&lt;br&gt;TWD-Taiwan Dollar&lt;br&gt;TZS-Tanzanian Shilling&lt;br&gt;THB-Thai Baht&lt;br&gt;TOP-Tonga Pa&#39;anga&lt;br&gt;TTD-Trinidad&amp;amp;amp;Tobago Dollar&lt;br&gt;TND-Tunisian Dinar&lt;br&gt;TRL-Turkish Lira&lt;br&gt;USD-U.S. Dollar&lt;br&gt;AED-UAE Dirham&lt;br&gt;UGX-Ugandan Shilling&lt;br&gt;UAH-Ukraine Hryvnia&lt;br&gt;UYU-Uruguayan New Peso&lt;br&gt;VUV-Vanuatu Vatu&lt;br&gt;VEB-Venezuelan Bolivar&lt;br&gt;VND-Vietnam Dong&lt;br&gt;YER-Yemen Riyal&lt;br&gt;YUM-Yugoslav Dinar&lt;br&gt;ZMK-Zambian Kwacha&lt;br&gt;ZWD-Zimbabwe Dollar&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;
        </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:ConversionRateSoapIn"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:ConversionRateSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="CurrencyConvertorHttpGet">
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            &lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Get conversion rate from one currency to another currency &lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font color=&#39;#000080&#39; size=&#39;1&#39; face=&#39;Verdana&#39;&gt;&lt;u&gt;Differenct currency Code and Names around the world&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;font face=&#39;Verdana&#39; size=&#39;1&#39;&gt;AFA-Afghanistan Afghani&lt;br&gt;ALL-Albanian Lek&lt;br&gt;DZD-Algerian Dinar&lt;br&gt;ARS-Argentine Peso&lt;br&gt;AWG-Aruba Florin&lt;br&gt;AUD-Australian Dollar&lt;br&gt;BSD-Bahamian Dollar&lt;br&gt;BHD-Bahraini Dinar&lt;br&gt;BDT-Bangladesh Taka&lt;br&gt;BBD-Barbados Dollar&lt;br&gt;BZD-Belize Dollar&lt;br&gt;BMD-Bermuda Dollar&lt;br&gt;BTN-Bhutan Ngultrum&lt;br&gt;BOB-Bolivian Boliviano&lt;br&gt;BWP-Botswana Pula&lt;br&gt;BRL-Brazilian Real&lt;br&gt;GBP-British Pound&lt;br&gt;BND-Brunei Dollar&lt;br&gt;BIF-Burundi Franc&lt;br&gt;XOF-CFA Franc (BCEAO)&lt;br&gt;XAF-CFA Franc (BEAC)&lt;br&gt;KHR-Cambodia Riel&lt;br&gt;CAD-Canadian Dollar&lt;br&gt;CVE-Cape Verde Escudo&lt;br&gt;KYD-Cayman Islands Dollar&lt;br&gt;CLP-Chilean Peso&lt;br&gt;CNY-Chinese Yuan&lt;br&gt;COP-Colombian Peso&lt;br&gt;KMF-Comoros Franc&lt;br&gt;CRC-Costa Rica Colon&lt;br&gt;HRK-Croatian Kuna&lt;br&gt;CUP-Cuban Peso&lt;br&gt;CYP-Cyprus Pound&lt;br&gt;CZK-Czech Koruna&lt;br&gt;DKK-Danish Krone&lt;br&gt;DJF-Dijibouti Franc&lt;br&gt;DOP-Dominican Peso&lt;br&gt;XCD-East Caribbean Dollar&lt;br&gt;EGP-Egyptian Pound&lt;br&gt;SVC-El Salvador Colon&lt;br&gt;EEK-Estonian Kroon&lt;br&gt;ETB-Ethiopian Birr&lt;br&gt;EUR-Euro&lt;br&gt;FKP-Falkland Islands Pound&lt;br&gt;GMD-Gambian Dalasi&lt;br&gt;GHC-Ghanian Cedi&lt;br&gt;GIP-Gibraltar Pound&lt;br&gt;XAU-Gold Ounces&lt;br&gt;GTQ-Guatemala Quetzal&lt;br&gt;GNF-Guinea Franc&lt;br&gt;GYD-Guyana Dollar&lt;br&gt;HTG-Haiti Gourde&lt;br&gt;HNL-Honduras Lempira&lt;br&gt;HKD-Hong Kong Dollar&lt;br&gt;HUF-Hungarian Forint&lt;br&gt;ISK-Iceland Krona&lt;br&gt;INR-Indian Rupee&lt;br&gt;IDR-Indonesian Rupiah&lt;br&gt;IQD-Iraqi Dinar&lt;br&gt;ILS-Israeli Shekel&lt;br&gt;JMD-Jamaican Dollar&lt;br&gt;JPY-Japanese Yen&lt;br&gt;JOD-Jordanian Dinar&lt;br&gt;KZT-Kazakhstan Tenge&lt;br&gt;KES-Kenyan Shilling&lt;br&gt;KRW-Korean Won&lt;br&gt;KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar&lt;br&gt;LAK-Lao Kip&lt;br&gt;LVL-Latvian Lat&lt;br&gt;LBP-Lebanese Pound&lt;br&gt;LSL-Lesotho Loti&lt;br&gt;LRD-Liberian Dollar&lt;br&gt;LYD-Libyan Dinar&lt;br&gt;LTL-Lithuanian Lita&lt;br&gt;MOP-Macau Pataca&lt;br&gt;MKD-Macedonian Denar&lt;br&gt;MGF-Malagasy Franc&lt;br&gt;MWK-Malawi Kwacha&lt;br&gt;MYR-Malaysian Ringgit&lt;br&gt;MVR-Maldives Rufiyaa&lt;br&gt;MTL-Maltese Lira&lt;br&gt;MRO-Mauritania Ougulya&lt;br&gt;MUR-Mauritius Rupee&lt;br&gt;MXN-Mexican Peso&lt;br&gt;MDL-Moldovan Leu&lt;br&gt;MNT-Mongolian Tugrik&lt;br&gt;MAD-Moroccan Dirham&lt;br&gt;MZM-Mozambique Metical&lt;br&gt;MMK-Myanmar Kyat&lt;br&gt;NAD-Namibian Dollar&lt;br&gt;NPR-Nepalese Rupee&lt;br&gt;ANG-Neth Antilles Guilder&lt;br&gt;NZD-New Zealand Dollar&lt;br&gt;NIO-Nicaragua Cordoba&lt;br&gt;NGN-Nigerian Naira&lt;br&gt;KPW-North Korean Won&lt;br&gt;NOK-Norwegian Krone&lt;br&gt;OMR-Omani Rial&lt;br&gt;XPF-Pacific Franc&lt;br&gt;PKR-Pakistani Rupee&lt;br&gt;XPD-Palladium Ounces&lt;br&gt;PAB-Panama Balboa&lt;br&gt;PGK-Papua New Guinea Kina&lt;br&gt;PYG-Paraguayan Guarani&lt;br&gt;PEN-Peruvian Nuevo Sol&lt;br&gt;PHP-Philippine Peso&lt;br&gt;XPT-Platinum Ounces&lt;br&gt;PLN-Polish Zloty&lt;br&gt;QAR-Qatar Rial&lt;br&gt;ROL-Romanian Leu&lt;br&gt;RUB-Russian Rouble&lt;br&gt;WST-Samoa Tala&lt;br&gt;STD-Sao Tome Dobra&lt;br&gt;SAR-Saudi Arabian Riyal&lt;br&gt;SCR-Seychelles Rupee&lt;br&gt;SLL-Sierra Leone Leone&lt;br&gt;XAG-Silver Ounces&lt;br&gt;SGD-Singapore Dollar&lt;br&gt;SKK-Slovak Koruna&lt;br&gt;SIT-Slovenian Tolar&lt;br&gt;SBD-Solomon Islands Dollar&lt;br&gt;SOS-Somali Shilling&lt;br&gt;ZAR-South African Rand&lt;br&gt;LKR-Sri Lanka Rupee&lt;br&gt;SHP-St Helena Pound&lt;br&gt;SDD-Sudanese Dinar&lt;br&gt;SRG-Surinam Guilder&lt;br&gt;SZL-Swaziland Lilageni&lt;br&gt;SEK-Swedish Krona&lt;br&gt;TRY-Turkey Lira&lt;br&gt;CHF-Swiss Franc&lt;br&gt;SYP-Syrian Pound&lt;br&gt;TWD-Taiwan Dollar&lt;br&gt;TZS-Tanzanian Shilling&lt;br&gt;THB-Thai Baht&lt;br&gt;TOP-Tonga Pa&#39;anga&lt;br&gt;TTD-Trinidad&amp;amp;amp;Tobago Dollar&lt;br&gt;TND-Tunisian Dinar&lt;br&gt;TRL-Turkish Lira&lt;br&gt;USD-U.S. Dollar&lt;br&gt;AED-UAE Dirham&lt;br&gt;UGX-Ugandan Shilling&lt;br&gt;UAH-Ukraine Hryvnia&lt;br&gt;UYU-Uruguayan New Peso&lt;br&gt;VUV-Vanuatu Vatu&lt;br&gt;VEB-Venezuelan Bolivar&lt;br&gt;VND-Vietnam Dong&lt;br&gt;YER-Yemen Riyal&lt;br&gt;YUM-Yugoslav Dinar&lt;br&gt;ZMK-Zambian Kwacha&lt;br&gt;ZWD-Zimbabwe Dollar&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;
        </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:ConversionRateHttpGetIn"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:ConversionRateHttpGetOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="CurrencyConvertorHttpPost">
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            &lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Get conversion rate from one currency to another currency &lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font color=&#39;#000080&#39; size=&#39;1&#39; face=&#39;Verdana&#39;&gt;&lt;u&gt;Differenct currency Code and Names around the world&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;font face=&#39;Verdana&#39; size=&#39;1&#39;&gt;AFA-Afghanistan Afghani&lt;br&gt;ALL-Albanian Lek&lt;br&gt;DZD-Algerian Dinar&lt;br&gt;ARS-Argentine Peso&lt;br&gt;AWG-Aruba Florin&lt;br&gt;AUD-Australian Dollar&lt;br&gt;BSD-Bahamian Dollar&lt;br&gt;BHD-Bahraini Dinar&lt;br&gt;BDT-Bangladesh Taka&lt;br&gt;BBD-Barbados Dollar&lt;br&gt;BZD-Belize Dollar&lt;br&gt;BMD-Bermuda Dollar&lt;br&gt;BTN-Bhutan Ngultrum&lt;br&gt;BOB-Bolivian Boliviano&lt;br&gt;BWP-Botswana Pula&lt;br&gt;BRL-Brazilian Real&lt;br&gt;GBP-British Pound&lt;br&gt;BND-Brunei Dollar&lt;br&gt;BIF-Burundi Franc&lt;br&gt;XOF-CFA Franc (BCEAO)&lt;br&gt;XAF-CFA Franc (BEAC)&lt;br&gt;KHR-Cambodia Riel&lt;br&gt;CAD-Canadian Dollar&lt;br&gt;CVE-Cape Verde Escudo&lt;br&gt;KYD-Cayman Islands Dollar&lt;br&gt;CLP-Chilean Peso&lt;br&gt;CNY-Chinese Yuan&lt;br&gt;COP-Colombian Peso&lt;br&gt;KMF-Comoros Franc&lt;br&gt;CRC-Costa Rica Colon&lt;br&gt;HRK-Croatian Kuna&lt;br&gt;CUP-Cuban Peso&lt;br&gt;CYP-Cyprus Pound&lt;br&gt;CZK-Czech Koruna&lt;br&gt;DKK-Danish Krone&lt;br&gt;DJF-Dijibouti Franc&lt;br&gt;DOP-Dominican Peso&lt;br&gt;XCD-East Caribbean Dollar&lt;br&gt;EGP-Egyptian Pound&lt;br&gt;SVC-El Salvador Colon&lt;br&gt;EEK-Estonian Kroon&lt;br&gt;ETB-Ethiopian Birr&lt;br&gt;EUR-Euro&lt;br&gt;FKP-Falkland Islands Pound&lt;br&gt;GMD-Gambian Dalasi&lt;br&gt;GHC-Ghanian Cedi&lt;br&gt;GIP-Gibraltar Pound&lt;br&gt;XAU-Gold Ounces&lt;br&gt;GTQ-Guatemala Quetzal&lt;br&gt;GNF-Guinea Franc&lt;br&gt;GYD-Guyana Dollar&lt;br&gt;HTG-Haiti Gourde&lt;br&gt;HNL-Honduras Lempira&lt;br&gt;HKD-Hong Kong Dollar&lt;br&gt;HUF-Hungarian Forint&lt;br&gt;ISK-Iceland Krona&lt;br&gt;INR-Indian Rupee&lt;br&gt;IDR-Indonesian Rupiah&lt;br&gt;IQD-Iraqi Dinar&lt;br&gt;ILS-Israeli Shekel&lt;br&gt;JMD-Jamaican Dollar&lt;br&gt;JPY-Japanese Yen&lt;br&gt;JOD-Jordanian Dinar&lt;br&gt;KZT-Kazakhstan Tenge&lt;br&gt;KES-Kenyan Shilling&lt;br&gt;KRW-Korean Won&lt;br&gt;KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar&lt;br&gt;LAK-Lao Kip&lt;br&gt;LVL-Latvian Lat&lt;br&gt;LBP-Lebanese Pound&lt;br&gt;LSL-Lesotho Loti&lt;br&gt;LRD-Liberian Dollar&lt;br&gt;LYD-Libyan Dinar&lt;br&gt;LTL-Lithuanian Lita&lt;br&gt;MOP-Macau Pataca&lt;br&gt;MKD-Macedonian Denar&lt;br&gt;MGF-Malagasy Franc&lt;br&gt;MWK-Malawi Kwacha&lt;br&gt;MYR-Malaysian Ringgit&lt;br&gt;MVR-Maldives Rufiyaa&lt;br&gt;MTL-Maltese Lira&lt;br&gt;MRO-Mauritania Ougulya&lt;br&gt;MUR-Mauritius Rupee&lt;br&gt;MXN-Mexican Peso&lt;br&gt;MDL-Moldovan Leu&lt;br&gt;MNT-Mongolian Tugrik&lt;br&gt;MAD-Moroccan Dirham&lt;br&gt;MZM-Mozambique Metical&lt;br&gt;MMK-Myanmar Kyat&lt;br&gt;NAD-Namibian Dollar&lt;br&gt;NPR-Nepalese Rupee&lt;br&gt;ANG-Neth Antilles Guilder&lt;br&gt;NZD-New Zealand Dollar&lt;br&gt;NIO-Nicaragua Cordoba&lt;br&gt;NGN-Nigerian Naira&lt;br&gt;KPW-North Korean Won&lt;br&gt;NOK-Norwegian Krone&lt;br&gt;OMR-Omani Rial&lt;br&gt;XPF-Pacific Franc&lt;br&gt;PKR-Pakistani Rupee&lt;br&gt;XPD-Palladium Ounces&lt;br&gt;PAB-Panama Balboa&lt;br&gt;PGK-Papua New Guinea Kina&lt;br&gt;PYG-Paraguayan Guarani&lt;br&gt;PEN-Peruvian Nuevo Sol&lt;br&gt;PHP-Philippine Peso&lt;br&gt;XPT-Platinum Ounces&lt;br&gt;PLN-Polish Zloty&lt;br&gt;QAR-Qatar Rial&lt;br&gt;ROL-Romanian Leu&lt;br&gt;RUB-Russian Rouble&lt;br&gt;WST-Samoa Tala&lt;br&gt;STD-Sao Tome Dobra&lt;br&gt;SAR-Saudi Arabian Riyal&lt;br&gt;SCR-Seychelles Rupee&lt;br&gt;SLL-Sierra Leone Leone&lt;br&gt;XAG-Silver Ounces&lt;br&gt;SGD-Singapore Dollar&lt;br&gt;SKK-Slovak Koruna&lt;br&gt;SIT-Slovenian Tolar&lt;br&gt;SBD-Solomon Islands Dollar&lt;br&gt;SOS-Somali Shilling&lt;br&gt;ZAR-South African Rand&lt;br&gt;LKR-Sri Lanka Rupee&lt;br&gt;SHP-St Helena Pound&lt;br&gt;SDD-Sudanese Dinar&lt;br&gt;SRG-Surinam Guilder&lt;br&gt;SZL-Swaziland Lilageni&lt;br&gt;SEK-Swedish Krona&lt;br&gt;TRY-Turkey Lira&lt;br&gt;CHF-Swiss Franc&lt;br&gt;SYP-Syrian Pound&lt;br&gt;TWD-Taiwan Dollar&lt;br&gt;TZS-Tanzanian Shilling&lt;br&gt;THB-Thai Baht&lt;br&gt;TOP-Tonga Pa&#39;anga&lt;br&gt;TTD-Trinidad&amp;amp;amp;Tobago Dollar&lt;br&gt;TND-Tunisian Dinar&lt;br&gt;TRL-Turkish Lira&lt;br&gt;USD-U.S. Dollar&lt;br&gt;AED-UAE Dirham&lt;br&gt;UGX-Ugandan Shilling&lt;br&gt;UAH-Ukraine Hryvnia&lt;br&gt;UYU-Uruguayan New Peso&lt;br&gt;VUV-Vanuatu Vatu&lt;br&gt;VEB-Venezuelan Bolivar&lt;br&gt;VND-Vietnam Dong&lt;br&gt;YER-Yemen Riyal&lt;br&gt;YUM-Yugoslav Dinar&lt;br&gt;ZMK-Zambian Kwacha&lt;br&gt;ZWD-Zimbabwe Dollar&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;
        </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:ConversionRateHttpPostIn"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:ConversionRateHttpPostOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorSoap" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorSoap12" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorHttpGet" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpGet">
    <http:binding verb="GET"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <http:operation location="/ConversionRate"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <http:urlEncoded/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="CurrencyConvertorHttpPost" type="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpPost">
    <http:binding verb="POST"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConversionRate">
        <http:operation location="/ConversionRate"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="CurrencyConvertor">
    <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorSoap" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap">
        <soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorSoap12" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorSoap12">
        <soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorHttpGet" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpGet">
        <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CurrencyConvertorHttpPost" binding="tns:CurrencyConvertorHttpPost">
        <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Replace your wsdl with this one. The difference to yours is, that the html content is escaped, which prevents the (invalid) html content to be validated. Also, I have never seen html tags within the wsd:documentation tag and am therefore not sure, if this is valid content.

Answer (score 0):

Error is at the end of line 201: "

"
End tag name 'font' does not match start tag name 'br'.

You can use XMLSpy (if available to you) to check well-formness
Also you can use Eclipse (right click on xml file and choose "Validate")